# How to draw this plot using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

im trying to build plot like this using TiKZ:

[image]

This what I'm doing:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (-3, 0) -- (4.2, 0) node[right] {$t$};
  \draw[->] (0, -3) -- (0, 4.2) node[above] {$S(t)$};
  \draw[scale=0.5, domain=-3:3, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {-(\x - 2) ^ 2 + 3});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But even this piece doesn't work at all

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet. And what has this to do with [tag:bibtex]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

You only need to fix the domain, the scale or the function definition. For example, removing the scale factor and applying it to the function y variable, and changing the domain:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (-1, 0) -- (5, 0) node[right] {$t$};
  \draw[->] (0, -1) -- (0, 2) node[above] {$S(t)$};
  \draw[domain=0:4, smooth, blue] plot (\x, {-0.5*(\x - 2) ^ 2 + 1.5});
  \node at ({2-sqrt(3)},0) [below right] {$\bar t$};
  \node at ({2+sqrt(3)},0) [below left]  {$t^b$};
  \draw[dashed] (2,1.5) -- (2,0) node [below] {$t^a$}; % <-- I can't see the original label
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output will be:
[image]

However, the original function looks more like a hyperbola to me. If that were the case:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (-1, 0) -- (5, 0) node[right] {$t$};
  \draw[->] (0, -1) -- (0, 2) node[above] {$S(t)$};
  \draw[domain=0:4, smooth, blue] plot (\x, {2-sqrt(1+(\x-2) ^2});
  \node at ({2-sqrt(3)},0) [below right] {$\bar t$};
  \node at ({2+sqrt(3)},0) [below left]  {$t^b$};
  \draw[dashed] (2,1) -- (2,0) node [below] {$t^a$}; % <-- I can't see the original label
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps that this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  \draw[->] (-.5, 0) -- (4.5, 0) node[right] {$t$};
  \draw[->] (0, -1.5) -- (0, 3.5) node[above] {$S(t)$};
  \draw[dashed] (2,0)--(2,3);
  \draw[domain=0:4, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {-(\x-2)^2+3});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

is what you're after. It will give you this:

[image]